# MYSQL Huge Data migration (5TB) from old server to new server

Tags: mysql, backup, migration, etl

We have an old MYSQL server  contains huge data ~5TB and wanted to migrate to the new server in order to minimize the costs and get rid of very old hardware.

My one and only idea in my mind is using mysqldump for the migration but I’m pretty sure that it’s a poor and risk option with that huge data.

Then someone in my team came up with the idea for using ETL tools but we haven’t go into the deeper details and not really sure if this ETL way can literally help us.

Any idea are always welcomed

thanks

Comment: Is there an overwhelming reason why cannot use a snapshot or xtrabackup?

Comment: *My one and only idea in my mind is using mysqldump* Reimporting 5Gb of data will be very long. Does the database scheme is too complex, or it is relatively simple? What is: tables amount, FKs amount, SP/UDF amount, etc.? Do you want to store server version, or you want to upgrade it at the same time?

Comment: Is there a way to migrate the storage to the new hardware and to place that into a mirrored raid?

Comment: Unix or Windows?

Comment: @RickJames It's Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

```
$ mysqldump -h source ... | mysql -h dest ...
```

I'm assuming:

- You have the tow machines (`source` and `dest`) set up.
- The two machines are "close" (not on opposite sides of the globe) so that network delays, etc would need to be considered
- That script would be run on one machine -- either one.
- If the versions are different, I cannot predict whether there will be some hiccups based on inconsistencies between versions.  If it fails running on one server, try the other.  If that fails come back with the error message(s).
- It will take time because 5TB takes time to read and write.

If the versions are radically different, there could be major changes that we need to discuss.